# Convert list to dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I convert a list

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

into a dictionary

```
my_dict = {
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c"
}
```

The keys should just be the indexes + 1 as in my example.

Comment: `di = dict(enumerate(my_list, 1))`

Comment: so what did you try?

Comment: @mohan3d: Comments are ok for hints, but answers should be in an actual answer, not a comment. And as you can see below, even a simple answer can earn you big points.

Comment: @PM2Ring , I don't care about points only to help others.

Comment: @mohan3d: Sure, but you help more people by putting answers where they belong, even if the answer seems trivial to you. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253045/4014959 and related questions for further info.

Comment: @mohan3d: If you wish to discuss this further, please come to the [SO Python Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Answer (score 19):

A simple solution is:

```
dict(enumerate(my_list, 1))
```

For example:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(["a", "b", "c"], 1))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 6):

Go for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

The `enumerate()` function adds a counter to an iterable.

Simple example:

```
for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    print i, v
```

By default, `enumerate()` starts counting at `0` but if you give it a second integer argument, it'll start from that number instead:

```
for i, v in enumerate(my_list, start=1):
    print i, v
```

For your case:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(your_list, start=1))
{1: 'your_list_value1', 2: 'your_list_value2'}
```